# Building a game, require advice on inventories

Tags: python, list

I am currently working on a game that I need a little help on.
Do you know how most games have an element where you can craft things with the things you have, like minecraft?
That is what I'm trying to here:

```
def craftitem(item):
    if item == 'applepie':
        try:
            inventory.remove('apple')
            inventory.remove('apple')
            inventory.remove('apple')
            inventory.remove('apple')
            inventory.append('applepie')
            print('Item crafted successfully.')
        except ValueError:
            print('You do not have the ingredients to craft this.')
```

This is a definition. I used the try command to achieve what might work: Use things in an inventory to make something else and add it back as an outcome.

And since code is run in order, meaning if something is run CORRECTLY, the next thing runs. If there is an error, it wouldn't run the next thing. Here is the problem: if you don't have the ingredients to craft it, it will still rip all of your stuff out of the inventory and return nothing.

Here is what I see:

> Working:

```
>>>inventory = ['apple','apple','apple','apple']
>>>
>>>craftitem('applepie')
Item crafted successfully.
>>>
>>>>inventory
['applepie']
```

> Not working:

```
>>>inventory = ['apple','apple','apple'] #Need one more apple
>>>
>>>craftitem('applepie')
You do not have the indredients to craft this.
>>>
>>>inventory
[]
```

Code rewrites, fixes, or advice appreciated.

I am a novice at python, only started like a month ago.

Comment: I would use IDs and ID slots using a dict. Instead of removing items from a list, I'd just clear an specific ID from the dict. That allowes me to add special info to each item like "quantity, value, vendor value, is_craftable, etc".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you'd want to do it count the number of required items in inventory to see there are enough to craft the item. For example:

```
num_apples = sum(item == 'apple' for item in inventory)
```

Answer (score 1):

You will soon realize that you want to use classes to deal with that. So your objects would be Inventory, Item, Recipe etc.

But to give you actual tip at the level you already are you can try doing it this way:

```
recipes = {'applepie': [('apple', 4)],
           'appleorangepie': [('apple', 4), ('orange', 2)]}

inventory = {'apple': 8, 'orange': 1}


def craft_item(item):
    ingredients = recipes.get(item)
    for (name, amount) in ingredients:
        if inventory.get(name, 0) < amount:
            print('You do not have the ingredients to craft this.')
            return
    for (name, amount) in ingredients:
        inventory[name] -= amount
    print('Item crafted successfully.')


craft_item('applepie')
print(inventory)

craft_item('appleorangepie')
print(inventory)
```

**Output:**

> Item crafted successfully.
>
> {'apple': 4, 'orange': 1}
>
> You do not have the ingredients to craft this.
>
> {'apple': 4, 'orange': 1}

Comment: actually that is good, instead of having duplicates in one list. So the definition defines the function for crafting, right?